# Pivot same values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a currency exchange table in SQL Server and I have the value of my local currency in other currencies

this is an example

[image: Example on excel]

```
1 Euro = 1.63 AUD
1 USD = 1.48 AUD
1 USD = 0.91 Euro
```

---

My table (Currency values) only has 2 columns, currency code and value of 148 different currencies, it has to show only the code on the first column, repeat it on the first row and cross the results of each one.

I tried to do it using a pivot, but doesn't seem to work.

[image: Here is my table]

I appreciate any help.

Comment: let me add the data in the question, thanks!

Comment: Add the data as text or dbfiddle. Maybe some one can then help.

Comment: SSMS is for ms sql server, not for mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try something dynamic.

For example:
[test](https://rextester.com/NKPM84056)

```
create table localcurrencies (
 code char(3) primary key, 
 value numeric(10,2)
);
insert into localcurrencies (code, value) values 
('AUD', 2.30), ('USD', 3.39), ('EUR', 3.73);

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = CONCAT(@cols+', ', QUOTENAME(code))
FROM localcurrencies
ORDER BY code;    

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT *',
' FROM (',
' select t1.code, t2.code as col, ',
' (t1.value/t2.value) as rate',
' from localcurrencies t1',
' cross join localcurrencies t2',
') src',
' PIVOT(max(rate) for col in (',@cols,')) pvt'
);


-- SELECT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```